# Subdomain vanity username rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, tumblr

I'm curious as to how Tumblr's vanity sub-domain works.

I'm not sure if its through an htaccess redirect but how would you rewrite:

```
myname.mywebsite.com
```

To:

```
www.mywebsite.com/profile.php?username=myname
```

Any pointers is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to rewrite anything. You can configure a web application instance or website (in IIS, Apache, etc) to respond to all requests, regardless of `Host` header (i.e. the domain name). The web application can then interrogate the `Host` header within application code and respond accordingly:

```
<?php
$domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if( $domainName == 'foo.mydomain.com' ) {
    // do something special?
} else {
    echo $domainName;
}
?>
```

Also note that the guide on Apache's website ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html ) states how to perform URI rewriting based on the `Host` header (see the section on "Virtual User Hosts"):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                 ^www\.[^.]+\.host\.com$
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
RewriteRule   ^www\.([^.]+)\.host\.com(.*) /home/$1$2
```

Comment: More directly he will need access to DNS record and web server in order to setup wildcards so that all sub-domains are sent to the web server, where the web server by its turn will handle all the requests. However if the web server does not have a `virtualhost` for that wildcard and handles multiple domains not from the same owner, the result would be a unrelated page. In order to avoid this the wildcard or sub-domains must be properly configured on its own `virtualhost`. After the wildcard is set on the DNS and web server you can use PHP or ASP or etc. to handle the pages or `.htaccess`.

Comment: How would this work for any sub domain I.e using $_server in php. I'm guessing you would need to check it against some regex?

Comment: @KwaasiDjin That depends entirely on your application. I cannot answer that question.